# Slash escape in javascript

Tags: javascript, escaping, slash

```
function slashEscape(strVar){
    var retVal = strVar;
    retVal = retVal.replace(/\\/g,"\\\\");
    return retVal;
}
```

I use that function to escape the slashes  in a certain string. But the result is not right.

```
var str = slashEscape("\t \n \s");
```

It will result to "s" instead of **"\t \n \s"**

Comment: `\t` is a tab character.  Your function probably should not exist; what are you trying to do?

Comment: I want the function to escape the slashes. and will output "\t \n \s" and not just "s"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the string constant `"\t \n \s"` is *instantiated* to a JavaScript string, it transforms `\t` to a tab character, the `\n` to a new line, and `\s` to a `s`.

That's why you can't replace `\` with `\\` because as far as JavaScript is concerned, there is no `\` character. There is only a tab character, a new line, and an `s`.

---

By the way, the result of `slashEscape("\t \n \s");` is **not** `"s"`. 
It's actually :

```
"    
s"
```

Which is a tab in the first line, a new line, then an s.

Comment: does this mean I can't escape the \t and \n, ever?

Comment: this is giving me a headache haha.

Answer (score 0):

To add on to what Mark Gabriel already said, it is the *parser*, and not any runtime code, that transforms escape sequences within your string. By the time the string is passed to your function, the parser has already removed the backslashes--they don't exist.